# Header scrolls to top when click menu active item

Tags: javascript, css

I have a sticky header, that I have set up using css and javascript. As well as a mega menu in the header. the issue is, when you scoll to the bottom, then click the more link for the dropdown, it's scrolls back to the top. I'm stumped on this. This is my javascript for the header and mega menu. this is the affected code. Like I said it functions correctly other than it scrolls to the top when I click the more link.

To make it easier, since I can't just post the whole index, here is the link. As I stated before it is an issue with the javascript.

http://beta.mstsage.com/sage-theme/

```
$(window).scroll(function() {    
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

    if (scroll >= 100) {
        $(".header-container").addClass("small");
    } else {
        $(".header-container").removeClass("small");
    }
});

$('.more').click(function(){
   $(this).toggleClass('active');
    $('.slide-down').toggle();
});

<div id="header-container" class="container-fluid header-container">

    //** Nav Menu
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
            <ul class="quick-links">
                <li class="quick-link">
                    <a href="#" class="link">News</a>
                </li>
                <li class="quick-link">
                    <a href="#" class="link">Videos</a>
                </li>
                <li class="quick-link">
                    <a href="#" class="link">Reviews</a>
                </li>
                <li class="quick-link">
                    <a href="#" class="link">Wikis</a>
                </li>
                <li class="quick-link more">
                    <a href="#" class="link">More
                        <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="mega-menu-container more-container slide-down">
    <div class="row no-gutters more-menu row-padding slide" style="height: 390px">
        <div class="col-12">
            <div class="row menu-content main-menu">
                <div class="col-6 menu-side left">
                    <h1 class="more-menu-label">MstSage Entertainment</h1>
                    <div class="row no-gutters cols-nav">
                        <div class="col-6">
                            <ul class="col-nav">
                                <li class="col-nav-link"><a href="#" class="link">About Us</a></li>
                                <li class="col-nav-link"><a href="#" class="link">Accessibility</a></li>
                                <li class="col-nav-link"><a href="#" class="link">Advertise</a></li>
                                <li class="col-nav-link"><a href="#" class="link">Careers</a></li>
                                <li class="col-nav-link"><a href="#" class="link">Content Team</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-6">
                            <ul class="col-nav">
                                <li class="col-nav-link"><a href="#" class="link">Press Release</a></li>
                                <li class="col-nav-link"><a href="#" class="link">Privacy Policy</a></li>
                                <li class="col-nav-link"><a href="#" class="link">Site Map</a></li>
                                <li class="col-nav-link"><a href="#" class="link">Standards</a></li>
                                <li class="col-nav-link"><a href="#" class="link">Terms of Use</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col menu-side right">
                    <div class="row cols-nav">
                        <div class="col-4">
                            <h1 class="text-center more-menu-label">Social</h1>
                            <ul class="align-items-center col-nav">
                                <li class="col-nav-link"><a href="#" class="link">Podcasts</a></li>
                                <li class="col-nav-link"><a href="#" class="link">YouTube</a></li>
                                <li class="col-nav-link"><a href="#" class="link">Facebook</a></li>
                                <li class="col-nav-link"><a href="#" class="link">Twitter</a></li>
                                <li class="col-nav-link"><a href="#" class="link">Twitch</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-4">
                            <h1 class="text-center more-menu-label">Entertainment</h1>
                            <ul class="align-items-center col-nav">
                                <li class="col-nav-link"><a href="#" class="link">Movies</a></li>
                                <li class="col-nav-link"><a href="#" class="link">TV Shows</a></li>
                                <li class="col-nav-link"><a href="#" class="link">Comics</a></li>
                                <li class="col-nav-link"><a href="#" class="link">Tech</a></li>
                                <li class="col-nav-link"><a href="#" class="link">Trailers</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-4">
                            <h1 class="text-center more-menu-label">Games</h1>
                            <ul class="align-items-center col-nav">
                                <li class="col-nav-link"><a href="#" class="link">PlayStation</a></li>
                                <li class="col-nav-link"><a href="#" class="link">Xbox</a></li>
                                <li class="col-nav-link"><a href="#" class="link">Nintendo</a></li>
                                <li class="col-nav-link"><a href="#" class="link">PC</a></li>
                                <li class="col-nav-link"><a href="#" class="link">Mobile</a></li>
                                <li class="col-nav-link"><a href="#" class="link">Upcoming</a></li>
                                <li class="col-nav-link"><a href="#" class="link">eSports</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="menu-content legal"><span class="legal-text">©2006-2018 MstSage Entertainment</span></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please always add all relevant code (HTML, CSS).

Comment: @ScottMarcus I posted the nav and part of the header, that is the only javascript i have in the site other than bootstrap 4s default script.

Comment: This is what you gave us: https://jsfiddle.net/fLqwjmu4/

Comment: I have added a link to the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why it jumps to the top is because you have the `href` of that `<a>` set to `#`, which is what it's supposed to do. Try replacing the `href="#"` with `href="javascript:void(0)` and it should work how you intended it to work. :)

Comment: Awesome! If you can accept my answer that would be great. :)

Comment: No problem, i just did.